# spark Potential conflict with org.iq80.snappy

Tags: java, apache-spark, thrift, snappy

I have some code that parses a snappy thrift file for objects.  This code works fine when run standalone (outside of the Spark environment).  However, when running from within Spark, I get an IllegalAccessError exception from the org.iq80.snappy package.  Has anyone else seen this error and/or do you have any suggestions?  Any pointers appreciated. 
Detail Exception information:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.iq80.snappy.BufferRecycler from class org.iq80.snappy.AbstractSnappyInputStream 
    at org.iq80.snappy.AbstractSnappyInputStream.<init>(AbstractSnappyInputStream.java:91) 
    at org.iq80.snappy.SnappyFramedInputStream.<init>(SnappyFramedInputStream.java:38) 
    at DistMatchMetric$1.call(DistMatchMetric.java:131) 
    at DistMatchMetric$1.call(DistMatchMetric.java:123) 
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1015) 
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328) 
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328) 
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727) 
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157) 
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reduceLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:172) 
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceLeft(Iterator.scala:1157) 
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:1011) 
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1$$anonfun$14.apply(RDD.scala:1009) 
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$36.apply(SparkContext.scala:1951) 
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$36.apply(SparkContext.scala:1951) 
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66) 
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89) 
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: having the same issue, devastated that there is no solution yet, have you found a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the same problem. It is because the spark env itself has a conflicting snappy dependency so execution in spark will fail, but execution locally will work. You should use your build system to shade the org.iq80.snappy package and that should solve your problem.